# How to override method's javadoc without overriding the method itself?

Tags: java, overriding, javadoc

Say I have two classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo {

    /**
     * Do bar. Subclasses may override this method, it is not required that they do baz.
     */
    public void bar() {
        // default implementation
    }

}

public class ConcreteFoo extends AbstractFoo {

    /**
     * Do bar. <b>Note:</b> does not do baz, you have to do it yourself.
     */
    @Override
    public void bar() {
        super.bar();
    }
}
```

In the subclass (`ConcreteFoo`) I want to override `bar()`'s javadoc but keep the implementation as in the super class (`AbstractFoo`). Is there any way to do this without overriding the method?

Comment: No. Why would you do that?

Comment: There's no point in doing such thing.

Comment: @HubertPopiołkiewicz I'd argue. See example above: in the abstract class I want to leave a note to those who will extend it, while in concrete implementations address those who will use it. E.g. "default implementation is not failsafe, subclasses may override this" vs "this implementation is failsafe/not failsafe"

Comment: On the other hand, I can write this in the javadoc for the class itself.

Comment: @null Just because you don't need it doesn't mean there is no point in doing it, e.g. if you need to be more specific about what `bar()` does in the specific context of the subclass.

Comment: If you use an obfuscator/optimizer, the overriden version would be simplified out anyway I guess, so what you did would be the only way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is absolutely no way of doing that.
You should, however, use the

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * add whatever you would like here
 */
```

notation as the implementation javadoc, if you plan on really overriding the method.

Answer (score 0):

No way to do that,but you can use the javadoc for the clone method:

> Creates a new object of the same class as this object. It then initializes each of the new object's fields by assigning it the same value as the corresponding field in this object. No constructor is called.

[According to this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076332/java-se/how-to-avoid-traps-and-correctly-override-methods-from-java-lang-object.html?page=2)